# Xamarin Forms api call does not return related entity include in json string

Tags: c#, json, api, xamarin

Have the following in my ApiController and it works

```
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public IEnumerable<GridPost> LoadDashboardAsync()
    {
        IEnumerable<GridPost> posts = _repo.GridPostRepository()
            .Include(m => m.LastModifiedByUser)
            .Where(a => a.IsActive == true)
            .OrderByDescending(s => s.DateLastModified);

        return posts;
    }
```

I can hit a breakpoint and see that the IEnumerable I named 'posts' contains the related user record (LastModifiedByUser is a nav property for an FK for one related user record and not a list/collection). All looks good on this end so far.

I then call this API from a ViewModel in my Xamarin Forms project. This works as far as the posts (GridPost entity itself). It loads and deserializes and displays just fine in my ListView in the XAML page, except the related entity does not appear at all. When setting a breakpoint, before even getting to the final line shown below to deserialize, the jsonRead returned by the ReadAsStringAsync() function does not contain the related user entity (there is a UserID FK field that does contain the ID, but the navigation property that contained the related user on the server did not come back in this json string - it is null). So the question is why does the related user disappear when returning from server to client?

```
    Task<HttpResponseMessage> response = _apiClient.SendAsync(loadChallenges);
        HttpResponseMessage _completed = await response;
        HttpContent jsonReturned = _completed.Content;
        var jsonRead = await jsonReturned.ReadAsStringAsync();

Posts = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ObservableCollection<GridPostModel>>(jsonRead) as ObservableCollection<GridPostModel>;
```

Example of returned JSON in the jsonRead variable as soon as assigned from the ReadAsStringAsync()

[{"$id":"1","title":"One and done","LastModifiedByUserId":"32e19260-7313-4eba-99b8-61077aced7a3","lastModifiedByUser":null}]

Comment: Looks to me like you're trying to deserialize the wrong thing. You want to JsonConvert your jsonRead variable first and check that that works in isolation. Your GridPostModel must match you GridPost class in a serialization sense further up. Hard to check without seeing the models also. Check also that your GridPost has been set up with DataContract and DataMember attributes.

Comment: Appreciate it! I'll still confused though! If you look at the second-to-last line in the code beginning "var jsonRead = await..." this utilizes the ReadAsStringAsync(). Hitting a breakpoint on this line shows this json string --- [{"$id":"1","title":"One and done","LastModifiedByUserId":"32e19260-7313-4eba-99b8-61077aced7a3","lastModifiedByUser":null}] --- I omitted other fields to keep it simple.  This shows the userID in the FK field but the lastModifiedByUser nav property is null. This is where the related entity data should appear. If it was not returned, what gets serialized won't matter?

Comment: I can't see your json data in the comments, it's better to add it to your question if you can edit it. Also post your GridPostModel code so we can see how that is laid out. You may find that the LastModifiedByUser property is not serializable, or is not loaded perhaps when the serializer runs. I prefer to convert my repository items into an array of models for sending across the wire.

Comment: What is the type of the 'lastModifiedByUser' property ?